# Definir o valor selecionado em uma SelectList (DropDownList)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

Tenho uma lista de modelos de veículos:

```
 private List<ModeloRastreador> modelo = new List<ModeloRastreador>();
```

adiciono o resultado que veio do banco

```
foreach (var m in modelo)
{
    modeloRastreador.Add(new SelectListItem { 
        Text = m.Nome, 
        Value = Convert.ToString(m.ID) 
    });
}
```

passo para a minha viewbag

```
 ViewBag.ModelosVeiculos = modeloVeiculos;
```

e para o dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("ModeloID", new SelectList(ViewBag.ModelosVeiculos, "value", "text"),
new { 
    style = "width:280px", 
    @class = "form-control form-control-last", 
    @id = "ModeloID" 
})
```

Até ai beleza, mas eu quero definir um valor, igual o selected do HTML.

Comment: Sim Tiago, isso mesmo, resolvi criando uma ViewBag.SelectedValue e passando no terceiro parametro do dropdown o value no caso o ID que veio do banco de dados, que era para ficar selecionado, ficando assim @Html.DropDownList("ModeloID", new SelectList(ViewBag.ModelosVeiculos, "value", "text", ViewBag.SelectedValue)

Answer (score 3):

Mude o código da View para que você possa escrever na propriedade `Selected`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModeloID, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ModelosVeiculos)
.Select(option => new SelectListItem {
    Text = option.Text,
    Value = option.Value,
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.ModeloID == Convert.ToInt32(option.ModeloID)
)}, "Escolha...", new 
{ 
    style = "width:280px", 
    @class = "form-control form-control-last", 
    @id = "ModeloID" 
})
```

Ou então mude o código no Controller (este exemplo seria para um `Edit`):

```
foreach (var m in modelo)
{
    modeloRastreador.Add(new SelectListItem { 
        Text = m.Nome, 
        Value = Convert.ToString(m.ID),
        Selected = (m.ID == modelSelecionado.ModeloID) 
    });
}
```

Comment: Eu consigo pegar o valor do dropdownlist criando ele em tempo de execução ?

Comment: @AndreeH Qual tempo de execução? Na *View* ou no *Controller*?

Comment: Tanto faz, eu preciso pegar o id selecionado no drop e fazer uma verificação com ele.

Comment: @AndreeH Sim, você pode. Preferencialmente monte a `DropDown` na *View*. Toda a responsabilidade de como a informação é apresentada é da *View*.